# Vim: Step by step guide on upgrading/updating vim on Mac OS X Mountain Lion with Homebrew

Tags: vim, installation, homebrew

What is a good step-by-step guide on installing the latest version of Vim on a
Mac Mini with Mountain Lion?

I would prefer to use Homebrew but it's not necessary. And, I would like for it
to be as feature rich as MacVim. I thought about adding the options manually
but, since I have *no idea* what Vim comes with and what should be added, I
decided to leave it to the experts.

Comment: It's OK on Stack Overflow, because Vim is one of the most commonly used [programming tools](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) in the world. The question isn't a good one though, because you could have researched the problem a bit more and found the same answer as given, that MacVim is the appropriate choice. It's Vim for the Mac, and functions at the command-line just as well as it does using its GUI, all from the same binary. That's standard for Vim on Linux also -- it's the same binary, just called a different name, which it senses at startup and uses its GUI mode.

Comment: @Greg OK, thanks for your info, I wasn't sure. :) I've figured out that using `brew install macvim --custom-icons --override-system-vim --with-python3` fixes my problem. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just download the latest Macvim snapshot, anything else is overkill.

MacVim comes with a `mvim` script for use at the command line. Place it somewhere in your `$PATH` and you can do `$ mvim -v filename` to start MacVim's `vim` executable right there, in your shell.

Comment: Using mvim launches MacVim, that doesn't workout if you're going to use tmux or something similar. :/

Comment: Did you read my answer? I've been using MacVim's CLI executable that way since more than two years. That's `$ mvim -v`, not `$ mvim`.

Comment: OH! Stupid stupid! Me of course. Thanks! That will work out perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can also just "brew install vim" to install vim stable 7.3.762. This is normal, console vim, not "MacVim".

Comment: I see, I was thinking about that. Although I remember reading somewhere that it's not a rich version. Is this statement true?

Comment: It's the latest tagged Vim from Google Code. It's the "huge" features version of Vim. See here for more info: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/ae12acb65644dc9a128cdb928e7aedf773c6a6f3/Library/Formula/vim.rb

Comment: I see, thanks! I ran `brew install macvim --override-system-vim` before this. You think that running this will mess it up?